# Retrieving data by NSUserDefaults Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

Currently, my code for NSUserDefaults work fine.  The only issue I have now is how can I send the data store to another page?  I can get it now save the data, but how do I retrieve that same data via NSUserDefaults to a secondary page?

```
import UIKit

    class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

        let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        @IBOutlet weak var name: UITextField!

        @IBAction func btnSave() {   

            if name.text == "" {

                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Data", message: "Missing Name.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }

            else {

                userDefaults.setObject(name.text, forKey:"name")

                userDefaults.synchronize()
            }
        }

        override func viewDidLoad() {

                super.viewDidLoad()

        }

        override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

                name.text = userDefaults.stringForKey("name")
        }
    }
```

Comment: `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("name") ?? ""` anywhere in your code

Comment: no need to force synchronization

Comment: There are better ways to pass data between controllers than `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: Yes, there better way to pass data but I'm just looking for something quick doesn't require recreating dictionary, ect.

Comment: I'd always prefer the more efficient way to the quick (lazy) way.

Comment: If you know the more efficient way, by all mean, let me know know how it done.

Comment: No offense, but there are thousands of questions and suitable answers on SO how to pass data between controllers.

Comment: Hmmm, I smell a troll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve your data from your second page with same code.
Create your `NSUserDefaults` in second page like this ;

First of all add these codes to your FirstPage in IBAction func. Don't use the if else statement for test.

```
UserDefaults.standard.set("yourValue", forKey: "yourKey")
```

When you press the button it should be save your data with your key.

In the secondPage you can retrieve your data in your viewDidLoad method like this;

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
print(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "yourKey") ?? "defaultValue in case key is not found")
print(value)
}
```

It should be print your value to your **console** (bottom window in your xcode) when the `secondPage` is open. If you still can't retrieve your value please share to me a your `storyboard` picture. I want to see your connections.

Comment: Tried it but for some reason, it's still not retrieving.  I'm trying to see if I can get the data to auto populate my textfield on the secondary page.

Comment: Thanks.  I work on it first thing tomorrow morning when I'm back at work.

Comment: Still doesn't work.  I have recreated the swift from scratch but couldn't get the data to retrieve.  I also have to change the let value = userDefaults.objectForKey ("name").  Otherwise, I would get an error message.

Comment: I am pretty sure these codes are working. I think you have a problem with connection between screens. Please show me a storyboard picture. I want to be sure your connection is ok.

Comment: I don't think it anything do with your end.  You want me to send you a jpg image of the story board?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105912/discussion-between-emresancaktar-and-coder).

Comment: Is there anyway I can upload an image file to our comment?

Comment: I got it working now.  Thanks!  I just need to get rid of my old code and start from the beginning.  My old code was interfering with the new one.  Again, thanks for your help Emersancaktar.